# How to add label to search input in material-table

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm using material-table version 1.69.2 which is latest now. I want to add a label to the search textfield displayed above the table.
Any help is much appreciated.

```
<MaterialTable
                title=""
                columns={[
                  { title: "id", field: "CurrencyKey", hidden: true },
                  { title: "Currency", field: "CurrencyName" },
                  { title: "Currency code", field: "CurrencyCode" },
                  { title: "Status", field: "IsDeleted" },
                  { title: "Last modified", field: "DateModified" }
                ]}
                data={data.list}
                icons={tableIcons}
                options={{
                  pageSize: 50,
                  pageSizeOptions: [50, 100, 150],
                  paginationPosition: "both",
                  searchFieldAlignment: "left",
                  search: true,
                }}
                localization={{ 
                  toolbar: {
                    searchPlaceholder: 'Search',
                    searchAriaLabel: 'Search here'
                  },
                  pagination: {
                    labelRowsSelect: 'Rows per page'
                  }
                }}
              />
```

Comment: It may not be what you are asking for but your `localization` definition is miss ordered. `searchTooltip` is a prop of `toolbar`, not `pagination`.

Comment: @NicoE, I have removed that filed. I want to add label for search field.